# How to add new language to android?

Tags: android, localization

Android os has many languages, but there is no my native language. Is it possible to add new language to android system?

P.S. I want to see my language in new versoin of Android.

Comment: are you trying to add it just to your own phone?

Comment: I want to see my language in new versoin of Android.

Comment: add the language in your application? - read this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html . Add language to your phone? -this question is not related to programming.

Comment: Well it kind of is related. You can contribute and do the translation work by yourself and with the help of your friends. After all, android is an open-source project. When you do that, open up a topic here for example: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/android-contrib 
I'm sure someone will notice your work ;) In the meantime, just wait for it. Some other languages are missing too ;)

Answer (score 0):

> want to see my language in new version of Android?

Though it  is not impossible, but not easy too, You can write to google, Android developer community. before doing that you can start translating english to your native language, tell them u have translation in your language. Write a thread on google-group for android developers , there are some people working as Android advocates/Engineers in google who provides help to developers, may be they can see ur concerns.

It is also dependent on Phone manufacturer companies, as Android is an open souce. All the companies basically sale phones with customized OS.